# extract number within brackets of callback value from api

Tags: jquery, api

I am receiving large amounts of data from an API call back that look like this:
response.endpoints[0].., response.endpoints[1].., response.endpoints[2].. etc

How can I get and set a variable for just the number within the brackets [] or directly extract this number.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
var a="response.endpoints[0].., response.endpoints[1].., response.endpoints[2]..";   
var b=a.split(",");
for(i=0;i<b.length;i++)
  alert(b[i].substring(b[i].lastIndexOf("[")+1,b[i].lastIndexOf("]")))
```

Comment: sorry, i should of mentioned. In the call back I don't know what the numbers will be it could be any number from 0-100 however the structure is always the same but the numbers are different..

for example: response.endpoints.[7].ipAddress

can you update your solution to factor this in ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for that, you can simply use plain JavaScript and either use String operations or regular expressions. With regular expressions you could do something like this:

```
var data = "response.endpoints[0].., response.endpoints[1].., response.endpoints[2]..";
var regex = /response\.endpoints\[(\d+)\]/g;
var match;
while (match = regex.exec(data)) {
    var number = match[1];
    console.log(number);
}
```

This will print the numbers 0 to 2 for the data above. If you're interested in the additional info (the `..` part), you will have to extend the regular expression.